# Swap Left Alt with Left Win in Saucy (13.10)

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

How do I swap the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the left <kbd>Super</kbd> ("windows") keys in Saucy Salamander? I just upgraded and I have noticed the keyboard layout dialog has changed, and I can no longer find the options window. I use this option because occasionally I use a Sun keyboard that has super next to space, which I'm not used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) to swap <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> with <kbd>Left Super</kbd>:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L"    #this will make Alt_L to act as Super_L
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L"  #this will make Super_L to act as Alt_L
```

To get this change for every session, after you have run the ​​previous commands create a file called `.xmodmap` with the new keymaps, using the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I don't find modifying the Xmodmap configuration every time I change keyboards (once or twice per day) very user friendly.

Comment: @Joni the change is permanent (for your user) if you create the `.xinitrc` file as he indicates

Comment: @Braiam, depending on where I am I use the laptop keyboard or the Sun keyboard with the funny layout, which means having to swap or unswap the keys almost every time I start work.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as accepted because it's more general and may help future visitors better even if it's not the best solution in my particular case.

Answer (score 12):

The layout options can be changed in [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool), in the "Typing" section. The setting to configure "Alt/Win key behavior" is the last one in the list.

Comment: While your answer is correct and straight to the point, this it can't be generalized to any two keys.

Comment: the "Typing" section doesn't appear to even be in the gnome-tweak-tool an
ymore...

Comment: Are you taking about the 14.04 beta @chrismarx? In 13.10 it's there.

Comment: Ah, I'm on 12.04, maybe that's the problem-

Comment: I believe in 12.04 this option was in the advanced settings in the main keyboard layout dialog. The advanced settings dialog was removed in 13.10, prompting this question.

Comment: Works great for Ubuntu 16.04 using a Mac keyboard

Comment: For MacBooks also set "Alternative Character Key" to "Right Win" in Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Typing, so you have a traditional AltGr.